# Asp.Net WebApi catch exceptions generated in controller constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, windows-authentication

In my base API controller class constructor, I am populating user permissions based on windows authentication. I am using something like

```
    var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, System.Environment.UserDomainName.ToUpper());
    var userInfo = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, System.Environment.UserName.ToUpper());
```

to get user information from AD. The problem is that when the user is locked out the application is failing with 500 since the exception occurs in the constructor. Is there a way to handle the exception of these calls and bubble it up as an Unauthorized exception or something else? I tried to surround it with try catch and throw httpresponse exception with unauthorized but it still bubbles up as 500.

**edit #1**

There are few more things happening in constructor and when it is failing I do not want to fail with 500. I need to catch the exception and throw something else. Authorization was just an example of one of those few things.

**edit #2**

To all who write that I should not have any logic in the constructor:

Constructors are used to initialize the object to a valid state. The controller of this part of the application has to have a database connection, user information and some other properties populated because all of the requests are using all this information. If any of those is failing I want to return a different type of the error to the user. In the case of a standard class it would be different type of exceptions (SqlException, DbConnectionException, Some sort of AD Exception). In the case of WebApi I want it to be a different type of the response codes (Unauthorized, Not Implemented (501) etc). Copy pasting the same code to every request in that section of the application represents a maintenance issue.

Comment: Copy-paste the same code in every method in the whole section of the application? This is even worse than having such logic in constructor. Please read the question: no matter what type of the exception is getting thrown in the constructor (even if I transform it to 400, 401 or whatever) it is getting translated to 500 by webapi. I want to find out how to avoid it being translated to 500. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the original exception is wrapped into other exceptions few times the only way I found so far is to have a global exception filter and then navigate through the inner exceptions of the context. Exception till it is null or I didn't reach the exception of the type I am looking for.

```
namespace SomeWebApi
{
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
    {
        public override async Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (context.Exception != null)
            {
                Exception filteredException = context.Exception;

                while (
                    (filteredException != null)
                    &&
                    (filteredException.GetType() != typeof(HttpResponseException)
                )
                {
                    filteredException = filteredException.InnerException ;
                }

                if (
                    (filteredException != null)
                    &&
                    (filteredException != context.Exception)
                )
                {
                    var httpResponseException = (HttpResponseException) filteredException;
                    var response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                        httpResponseException.Response.StatusCode,
                        httpResponseException
                    );

                    context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next I needed to register it in WebApiConfig.Register:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
```

Answer (score -1):

The eseaiest way is to not use user / sesion related logic in controllers constructor.
For authentication You can use attribute filters, for geting user information just create helper class and use it when needed.

**edit**

one last thing: try to use dependency injection (like structure map) it will force You to make proper changes in constructor and it will make initializing easier. https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/setting-up-dependency-injection-in-web-api-with-structuremap/

Comment: The problem is not only authorization. There are few more things happening in base controller and when it fails I need to throw something other than 500.

Comment: Same thing. Just dont put request related logic into constructor. 
Requests are supported in controllers action, not in constructor, you shouldn't send response for request in controller.

Comment: Yep, copy-paste same code in 100 requests. That is totally safe and not dangerous.

Comment: 1) You don't understand what request is. You can't "copy-paste same code in 100 requests". You probobly talk about action, but i am prety shure that you don't have 100 actions in one controller (and even if you have 100 actions in a controller, then this is separate problem that You have to resolve... )
2) There are many ways to do something globaly (app start, modules, handlers, filters etc. 
3) You just can't properly return response to request in constructor. If yoou have logic that you expect to throw exception in constructor, then You are doing something wrong.

Comment: Please read my original question. This is a base controller that is inherited by multiple others (not all) controllers. All of the actions under such controllers have to access to specific things: ad user infotmation, database context, etc. Initializing these pieces of data can cause different exceptions. Since this is exactly same data and logic to initialize it exactly the same across 100 different endpoints then it was placed in the constructor of the baseclass (which is corresponds with OOP). What you have said so far has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Your original post was: "The problem is that when the user is locked out the application is failing with 500 since the exception occurs in the constructor" Insted of telling You how to workaround this, i said what you are doing wrong. And You said: "It's not helping, because i am doing many things wrong, so fixing this one will not help"...

Comment: This is wrong only in your mind: the purpose of the constructor is to initialize an object to a valid state: this means that if every methods in the class needs db connection of a same type it should be initialized in constructor. If every method under the class needs user information: it goes in the constructor. Otherwise you end up with the methods either with copy pasted code or side effects. Also I really like how you was able to "identify" that I am doing "many things wrong" withot even knowing anything about what is done.

Comment: This conversation dosn't have any purpose. Last comment from me. 
Initializing DbContext should never throw exception in constructor, thats why it's ok to use it in constructor. Exception can be throw durring opening connection, but its much later then in constructor. 
"User info" is request related. You shold never initzilize it in constructor. 
In constructor You shold initzilize repositories, servieces, dbContext, etc. 
Dosn't meter what is in constructor, if you throwing exceptions there, then You are doing something wrong. That's all.

Comment: one last thing: try to use dependency injection (like structure map) it will force You to make proper changes in constructor and it will make initializing easier. https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/setting-up-dependency-injection-in-web-api-with-structuremap/

Comment: "In constructor You shold initzilize repositories, servieces, dbContext, etc". We're getting closer. Now I would like to separate failure of dbContext initialization from service initialization failure (one of which is ad) via different exception type that is a different response code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163013/discussion-between-garret-and-alexanderm).